# Why 'deleted entity passed to persist'-exception is raised?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

i' trying to create simple web-app, which will contain topics and comments.
Topic model:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "T_TOPIC")
public class Topic {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    private int id;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="USER_ID")
    private User author;

    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)    
    private Tag topicTag;

    private String name;
    private String text;

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, mappedBy = "topic", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private List<Comment> comments;

    // We shouldn't read whole collection to get this basic info
    private int commentsCount;
    private Date timeLastUpdated;

     /**
     * Removes comment from the Topic entity
     * @param comment
     */
     public void removeComment(Comment comment) {
            // updating topic
            timeLastUpdated = Utils.getCurrentTime();
            commentsCount--;
            comments.remove(comment);

     }
}
```

Comment model:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "T_COMMENT")
public class Comment
{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    private int id;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="TOPIC_ID")
    private Topic topic;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="USER_ID")
    private User author;

    private String text;
    private Date creationDate;
}
```

The Comment service:

```
@Service
@Transactional
public class CommentService {

    @Autowired
    private CommentRepository commentRepository;

    public int saveComment(Comment comment){
         return commentRepository.save(comment).getId();

    }   

    public Comment findCommentByID(int id){
        return commentRepository.findOne(id);
    }

     /**
     * Deletes a comment
     * @param comment -- a comment to delete
     * @return id of a topic
     */
     public int deleteComment(Comment comment) {
         int result = comment.getTopic().getId();
         commentRepository.delete(comment);
         return result;
     }
}
```

The controller's method, which is deleting the Comment:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/deleteComment/{commentId}", method = {RequestMethod.POST, RequestMethod.GET} )
public String deleteComment(@PathVariable int commentId, @ModelAttribute("comment")Comment comment, BindingResult result, Model model){
    Topic parentTopic;
    Comment deletedComment = commentService.findCommentByID(commentId);
    if (deletedComment != null) {
         // remove any relations
         parentTopic = deletedComment.getTopic();
         parentTopic.removeComment(deletedComment);
         // rempve the comment itself
         commentService.deleteComment(deletedComment);
        }
         //return "refresh:";
         return "home";
}
```

deleted entity passed to persist: [com.epam.mvc3.model.Comment#]

Comment: Can you show the full stacktrace? Also, make sure that you don't have other `@OneToMany` relationships to `Comment` (for example, from `User`).

Comment: Without the stacktrace it's difficult but is your repository Merging the object you passed back and then trying to delete? Could it be deleting the comment because you merge it without a Topic and then the delete call is trying to delete something that's already gone?

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't have to remove the Comment object from the collection in Topic yourself if you then delete it from your repository and I'm thinking that doing that has caused your merge to delete the comment, and the delete to try and delete and already deleted Comment.

Try changing it to remove the Comment from the Topic and then save the Topic instead. Or create a method in the service that runs a query to count the number of Comments for a given Topic without reading the whole collection.

Although the Comment fetch type is eager so why not just use `comments.size()`?

Answer (score 0):

Change your deleteComment() as follows,

```
public int deleteComment(int commentId) 
{

         Comment existingComment = findCommentByID(commentId);
         if(existingComment != null)
         {

             int result = existingComment .getTopic().getId();
             Topic existingTopic = existingComment .getTopic();
             existingTopic.remove(existingComment) 
             topicRepository.save(existingTopic);// spring 3.1
             topicRepository.merge(existingTopic);// spring 3.0
             return result;

          }

       return 0;

     }
```

The point here is that we need to always use the parent dao/repository to handle the children.

So first remove the comment from topics and the save/merge the topic using the topicRepository .